# How to hide certain json data from passing through if it doesn't meet a condition in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Hello all I want to hide certain json data from passing through if it doesn't meet a condition in django rest framework, like I have a comment model and serializer, and I don't want the replies to pass through as comments since I have another field for replies which is nested along with the respective comments.

These are the serializers:

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content         = serializers.CharField()
    reply_id        = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='reply',queryset=Comment.objects.all(),
                            write_only=True, required=False)    
    user            = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.username")

    class Meta:
        model       = Comment
        fields      = ['id', 'user', 'content', 'reply_id', 'timestamp']

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content         = serializers.CharField()
    reply_id        = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source='reply',queryset=Comment.objects.all(),
                            required=False)
    user            = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.username")
    replies         = CommentCreateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model       = Comment
        fields      = ['id', 'user', 'content', 'replies', 'reply_id', 'timestamp']
```

This is the current json response:

```
"count": 5,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": "testuser2",
        "content": "comment test!",
        "replies": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user": "testuser3",
                "content": "ding",
                "timestamp": "2021-02-09T15:29:38.230933+01:00"
            }
        ],
        "reply_id": null,
        "timestamp": "2021-02-09T15:24:11.072502+01:00"
    },

    {
        "id": 3,
        "user": "testuser3",
        "content": "ding",
        "replies": [],
        "reply_id": 2,
        "timestamp": "2021-02-09T15:29:38.230933+01:00"
    },
]
}
```

This is what I need.

```
"count": 5,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user": "testuser2",
        "content": "comment test!",
        "replies": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user": "testuser3",
                "content": "ding",
                "timestamp": "2021-02-09T15:29:38.230933+01:00"
            }
        ],
        "reply_id": null,
        "timestamp": "2021-02-09T15:24:11.072502+01:00"
    },

]
}
```

UPDATE:

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post            = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_comments") 
    reply           = models.ForeignKey('Comment', null=True, related_name='replies', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content         = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
class CommentPostAPIView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    # pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post                = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments            = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
        paginator           = CustomPaginator()
        response            = paginator.generate_response(comments, CommentSerializer, self.request)
        return response
```

Here I want to hide the replies from showing up along with the comments as replies are already nested along with respective comments. so comments with `reply_id` are actually replies and one with null `reply_id`'s are comments. How can I prevent those from passing through.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CommentSerializer` is correct problem is you are getting all comments and related replies from `Comment` model in your view and passing to `CommentSerializer` you need to filter and remove reply related to comment

```
Comment.objects.filter(reply_id__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, I tried this, but its giving me the same response. no change at all.

Comment: @Danny i have update my answer please try once more i don't have data to test but according to logic it should work.

Comment: @Danny if still does'nt work can you share sample data

Comment: II tried it again. no luck, still the problem exists. What data you need? I just have some random text as data and some user info.
Do you want me to share the model?

Comment: @Danny yes can you share model and sample data it would be helpful for making sure that solution works

Comment: I have updated the question with the models, but How do I share sample data?
like I have some testusers accounts and random words as comment objects. :)
similar to the json response above..

Comment: @Danny only comments table sample data.

Comment: @Danny can you also share `django version`, `rest_framework` version and how you are using `CommentSerializer` it seems to be working correctly on my side .

Comment: Hey, Iam using django 2.2.13 and rest framework 3.11.0. I will update the question with my view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228638/discussion-between-chandan-and-danny).

Answer (score 0):

set `reply_id` field as [**`write_only`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only)

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.CharField()
    reply_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        source='reply',
        queryset=Comment.objects.all(),
        required=False,
        write_only=True
    )
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="user.username")
    replies = CommentCreateSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'content', 'replies', 'reply_id', 'timestamp']
```

Comment: Hey, I actually want to filter out the entire reply object from the response, not a particular field. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Serializers validation will work fine in this case.
If you need to add a condition to a specific field then create a method `validate_fieldname` and if you want to add condition over a specific object then directly create a method as `validate`.

You can read the documentation for more information - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need to filter as @Chandan said before. So really you need to refactor your view with the `reply_id` filter

```
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) 
    # pagination_class = PageNumberPagination

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        post                = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments            = Comment.objects.filter(post=post,reply_id__isnull=True)
        paginator           = CustomPaginator()
        response            = paginator.generate_response(comments, CommentSerializer, self.request)
        return response
```